# Shell Script If Statement to compare dates

Tags: bash, shell, date, hive

I am currently working on a shell script to run some hive queries I have.  I need to check the last date in the table before I run it.  I want to check the date and pass it as a result then compare it to my date variable.  I am doing this as an if statement so if the date is yesterday then it should run the hive query.  If not(which means the date is older and the data hasn't been refreshed) I just want it to send me an email telling me so.  I have all of the logic figure out except how to compare the dates.  Every thing I try with reguards to = or -gt, -lt etc.  I always get the THEN statement, it will no check the first compare as matching.  Below is the code I used.  I have the then statement, even tell me what dates it finds.  So even the email will say the VAL1 = 2020-06-26 and yesterday was 2020-06-26( I set it to pick this date bc this is whta I am testing with.  So the output tells me that the dates are the same, but the IF statement is not marking them as true.

This is my query:

```
#!/bin/bash
yesterday=`date -d "$date -3 days" +"%Y_%m_%d"`;
today=`date '+%Y_%m_%d'`;

cd /idn/home/chalse/AutoJobs
result=`hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false;select max(asgn_dt) from acorn_data.katie_rr;"`

if [ $result -eq $yesterday ]
then

echo "Hi Katie,

The last update for Reserve & Reactivation was $result .

Yesterday is $yesterday

Thanks, 
CJ" | mailx -s "Reserve Reactivation Report $yesterday" - name@email.com

else 

echo "Hi KAtie,

The last update for Commission File was $result.   We even checked $today but we did not check $yesterday

Thanks,
CJ" | mailx -s "Reserve Reactivation Report $today" - name@email.com

fi
```

I get this as my email showing the then statement The first date represents the output from the select hive query variable.  The second is just today varilable, and the third date is the $yesterday  Even though the outputs both show that the answer is 2020-06-26 the IF statement doesn't recognize them as matching.

```
"Hi KAtie,

The last update for Commission File was 2020-06-26($result).   We even checked 2020_06_29($today) but we did not check 2020-06-26($yesterday)

Thanks,
CJ"
```

Comment: You're using `-` as the separator in one date, and `_` as the separator in the other. Use consistent separators.

Comment: That was a typo on my part they are both using underscore.  You an see in the results at the bottom $result and $yesterday botho show 2020-06-26 but my IF is not evaluating as TRUE

Comment: `$today` in the output has `_`.

Comment: But `$result` and `$yesterday` have `-`.

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting an error using `-eq` to compare non-integers ... ?
  have you tried `[ "${result}" = "${yesterday}" ]` ?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script. This will show all the statements as they execute, with the variable values so you can see what's happening.

Comment: I added the `set -x` to it and this was my result:
`line 9: [: 2020-06-26: integer expression expected`
line 9 is where the IF statement is but it's not showing

Comment: @Sotark `-eq` is used for comparing integers; `2020-06-26` is not an integer so you're getting this error; try replacing `-eq` with `=`

Comment: Thank you so much @markp-fuso  As you suggested once I swapped the = and added the quotes around it, it worked.  This was so help ful.  Also a thank you to Barmar as the set -x really let me see where things where failing and will be in all of my shell's going forward.

Comment: keep in mind that `set -x` is useful for debugging purposes; once you've got a script working properly make sure to remove the `set -x` else you'll generate a **LOT** of unwanted output during normal operations

Answer (score 0):

Looks like hive is query is returning more than just a date. I am assuming it is returning log data.

```
hive_result=`hive -S -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false; select max(asgn_dt) from acorn_data.katie_rr;"
```

Once you have the `hive_result` then try to split based on delimiter.

```
result=$(echo $hive_result| cut -d'_' -f 1)
```

Next try comparing both the results like below:

```
if [[ $result -eq $yesterday ]]
...
```